# clinfo can't find intel HD GPU on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencl, gpu, beignet

I have a Intel Atom E3845 with an included Intel HD graphics card, which should support OpenCL. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and installed beignet, `ocl-icd-dev`, and other packages.

When I run clinfo, it finds one device of type `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU`, i.e. the system (clinfo) does not find the GPU. Same is with clGetPlatformIDs.
Here is the output of `lshw`:
`lshw -c video
 *-display
 description: VGA compatible controller
 product: ValleyView Gen7
 vendor: Intel Corporation
 physical id: 2
 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
 version: 11
 width: 32 bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
 configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
 resources: irq:114 memory:a0000000-a03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:e080(size=8)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- Download the Intel drivers from [Intel's OpenCL Driver Download](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) page.
- Uninstall beignet: `sudo apt purge beignet`. You can always reinstall it later if you want, but Intel says purge it.
- Install the Intel drivers.
- Profit

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, the drivers on the homepage are only for Atom E39.. series, while I have an 3845. I did not find an alternative on the intel page, and according to [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl/topic/591696) it seems that intel does not support it in my case. So I try beignet.

Comment: Since Atom is their low-power brand, this doesn't surprise me. I wonder if the CPU side would be faster or lower power.

Comment: I compiled and installed beignet 1.3 and clinfo finds the GPU now.